# Create Tuple with more than 2 arguments

Tags: c#, tuples

I want to convert

```
List<Tuple<IntPtr, string, string>>
```

into

```
Dictionary<IntPtr, Tuple<string,string>>
```

using

```
ToDictionary
```

i.e.

```
var T = new List<Tuple<IntPtr, string, string>>();
T.ToDictionary(/*I cannot figure out the right syntax*/);
```

All examples I could find have just 2 arguments while I have 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [Enumerable.ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which accepts both key and value selectors:

```
T.ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => Tuple.Create(t.Item2, t.Item3))
```

But keep in mind, that there should not be duplicated pointers in your list.

Comment: If you might have duplicate pointers, you can use `ToLookup` instead